# Adding UIVisualEffectView also over tab bar

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create modal popup with `UIVisualEffectView` as it's background. I want the `UIVisualEffectView`to be over the tab bar but I do not see the way to achieve it.

This is what I do but this is not the output I want:

```
var visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
visualEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
tabBarController?.view.addSubview(visualEffectView)

//Also tried like this
self.view.window?.addSubview(visualEffectView)
```

This is pretty much what I am looking for:

[image]

So my question is, how should I add the `UIVisualEffectView` to be over tab bar also as a subView. I know I could make another viewController and present it as `.OverCurrentContext` but this is not a solution for me.

Comment: @brandonscript can you be more specific. I can't understand what do you mean at the moment. What do you mean by "add the view in parallel"?

Comment: This is not working also.

Comment: Weird, tabBarController?.view.addSubview(visualEffectView) works fine for me

Comment: @algrid does it cover the tab bar also for you?

Comment: Yes, it covers the tab bar.

Comment: @algrid I just tested it with clean project and you are right, it works. So weird that it doesn't work with my existing project. For some reason my view frame is 618 instead of 667.

Comment: You tab bar may be non-translucent, I added the answer explaining that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced the problem adding the visualEffectView to UITabBarController's main view. For **non-translucent** tab bar view controller views are not extended under it, so the height is shorter than you need.

To fix the problem change

```
visualEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
```

to:

```
visualEffectView.frame = self.tabBarController!.view.bounds
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much. Can't believe that non-translucent tab bar caused me so much trouble.

Comment: How can I make visualEffectView above tab bar but behind one controllerview's subview?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach it to the view hierarchy, but I wouldn't recommend doing it this way in a production app; plenty of room for bugs and crashes when the view stack changes (rotate, for example). Still, it gets the job done:

```
class tabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        let visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
        visualEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
        let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow ?? UIApplication.shared.windows[0]
        window.subviews[0].addSubview(visualEffectView)
    }
}
```

What you could (argue: should) do instead is create a custom protocol and  delegate that shows and hides your modal view when needed on each of the tab bar's view controllers (which could in turn each be subclassed to handle the delegate).